# how to limit form array length?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have an form array which i want to limit to only 5 input elements generated by user 
and my form has following definition

```
 createskillForm()
    {
      this.skillForm=this.formBuilder.group({
        skills:this.formBuilder.array([this.createskillFeild()],Validators.minLength(1),Validators.maxLength(5))
      });
    }
```

i have tried making changes with minlength but it is showing the following error in the console :-
RROR in src/app/components/com-profile/com-profile.component.ts(47,89): error TS2345: Argument of type 'ValidatorFn' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[]'.
  Type 'ValidatorFn' is not assignable to type 'AsyncValidatorFn'.
    Type 'ValidationErrors' is not assignable to type 'Promise | Observable'.
      Type 'ValidationErrors' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
        Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'ValidationErrors'.
what i can do to limit adding user only five skills ?

Comment: is there a method creating each new form? if there is, you could start in it with 

`if (this.myFormArray.controls.length >= 5) return;` this example will vary with each particular case, but you get the idea.

If this is a method, do tell me to add it as an answer! Hope it helps.

Comment: The 'space' character is your friend; not your enemy.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your validators in an array. The error you're getting is because maxLength isn't an async validator, which is the variable you're putting it into..

```
constructor(formState: any = null, validatorOrOpts?: ValidatorFn | >AbstractControlOptions | ValidatorFn[], asyncValidator?: AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[])
```

This is the correct code below. Not sure if this solves the problem you're trying to solve, but it fixes the error you have right now.

```
this.skillForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        skills:this.formBuilder.array([this.createskillFeild()], [ Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(5)] )
      });
```

Comment: It is still adding more than 5 fields and i want user to be able to add 5 fields only

Comment: I thought it would still add more than 5 fields. I believe the length validator is for string or number length only. Add the Validators.required validator to the array and that should fix it. Otherwise it would need a custom validator (which is a really easy one to do in this case).